# Encryption string on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

just wanted to verify if on Codeigniter Encryption say like this one

**hhNa0fUcOc3k0jUhPcRBJshpiXLpUSug+NhgPk89O7eSjerHk6go360U9rl8LazZo6DR6M1N4IqG0PYIwPyKhQ==**

Is the structure of this string always have a '+', '=' and a '/' character?. Just wanted to verify things before i parse them. Is there a case wherein when a string is encrypted it may contain special character other than '+, =, /' signs? Just a heads up, i didn't used any mcrypt thing other than the default specified on CI.

Comment: The encrypted data in CI comes out as binary, to convert it to a string, the data is Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a [base-64 encoded string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). `+` and `/` are valid characters, and `=` are padding which will always show up on the end. `+`, `/` and `=` are the only special characters in a standard base-64 implementation.

Answer (score -1):

use this to remove `=` from the encoded string while using base64_encode

```
<?php echo  rtrim(base64_encode($content_string),'=') ?>
```

Comment: i wanted to decode this back by the way so i need this to be reparsed. :D