# Encode/Decode not always working - Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a delete button which deletes from the database. I press the delete button on my page and it will not do anything until I press it for a couple of times. Sometimes, it just deletes the value from database in one try, other times, I have to keep pressing the delete button a cuple of times for it to delete. Any way to get over this?

My view file:

```
//other code above

<?php $encrypted = $this->encrypt->encode($data->pid); ?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url() . "profile/delete_entry/" .  $encrypted; ?>">Delete</a>

//other code below
```

My controller:

```
$this->load->model('model_entry');

    $pid = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $result = $this->model_entry->entry_delete($pid);
    //redirect to entries index.php
```

My Model

```
public function entry_delete($pid) {

    $pid = $this->encrypt->decode($pid); //to decode

    $uid=$this->session->userdata('uid');

    $whereConditions = array('pid' => $pid, 'uid' => $uid);
    $this->db->where($whereConditions);

    $this->db->delete('dayone_entries');
}
```

Comment: Did you load the $this->load->library('encrypt'); http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html I do not see it in entry_delete. Or have you auto loaded it.

Comment: Hey, I have it autoloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can place encrypted data in your URL. Codeigniter will not permit you to use a URL with special character like '='. As i know, if you do something like `$encrypted = $this->encrypt->encode($data->pid);` it will return a string with double '=' at the end.

Here is an explanation about encryption in CodeIgniter. [Encryption string on Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534510/encryption-string-on-codeigniter)

Comment: I have this in my config.php: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=\a-z 0-9~%.:_-';`

So what would be the best way? Thanks

Comment: do you have the same problem?

Comment: yeah, finally agree with @TaylorSwift, add '=' in permitted_uri_chars

Comment: I did. And I have to press teh delete button a couple times to delete it.

Comment: oh i think i get it..just check your encrypted data, is there '/' ? If the character exist, your `$pid = $this->uri->segment(3);` will not get full encrypted data

Comment: Oh god. Yes. There is a "/". How do I fix this?

Comment: just do some `do while` in your controller to make sure that your encrypted data have no '/' character..then place it in your url.. I think it's all